# Removing recyclerview items from the Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley, notifydatasetchanged

I have two tabs (fragments), NewOrders and FinishedOrders, I'm populating the orders via Volley requests, now each item inside the New Orders tab has a [SwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/) which show a clickable textview that makes the order finished, and move it to the other tab (backend stuff..), and I got this working perfectly,

The problem is when I click to finish, the recyclerview isn't updated once the request sent successfully, I have to do pull-to-refresh so it would update..! it seems easy to solve, but the issue is handling the swipelayout listener done inside onBindView method inside the adapter..!! that's only place to access it according to the library I'm using (I guess)..! on the other hand refreshing and populating the list happens in the NewOrder tab fragment..! 
So how can I make the item to be removed from the list after the click and becomes updated..?!

Any thoughts..!?

**My Adapter Class + ViewHolder**

> Note: the implemented methods in the adapter are required because of the interface of SwipeLayout library

```
 public class OrdersDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    implements SwipeAdapterInterface, SwipeItemMangerInterface {

protected SwipeItemRecyclerMangerImpl mItemManger = new SwipeItemRecyclerMangerImpl(this);

public Context context;
ArrayList<OrderPresenter> orders;


public OrdersDataAdapter(ArrayList<OrderPresenter> orders, Context context) {
    this.orders = orders;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_card, parent, false);

    return new NewOrderVH(v);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final OrderPresenter order = this.orders.get(position);
    final NewOrderVH vh1 = (NewOrderVH) holder;

    vh1.setData(orders.get(position));
    mItemManger.bindView(vh1.itemView, position);
    vh1.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);
    vh1.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, 
    vh1.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));


    if (order.isFinished()) {
        vh1.swipeLayout.setSwipeEnabled(false);
        vh1.setBadge("DONE");              
        vh1.setBadgeColor(order.getBadgeColor());

    } else {

        vh1.finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // get the clicked item position?
                final int position = vh1.getAdapterPosition();

          // these responsible for the request which make the order finished
                OrderPresenter order = orders.get(position);
                OrderRepository.setOrderFinURL(order.getID());
                OrderRepository.FinishOrder(order.getID(), context);

        /*the commented three lines below didn't help with the problem*/ 
                 // notifyItemChanged(position);
                 // notifyItemRemoved(position);
                 // notifyDataSetChanged();*/

               order.setStatus(order.getStatusText(Order.FINISHED));

            }
        });
    }


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return orders.size();
}


public class NewOrderVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
    private TextView finish;
    private CardView orderCard;
    TextView Badge;
    private ImageView cusPic;
    private TextView cusName;
    private TextView CusAdress;
    private TextView vendorsNum;
    private TextView itemsNum;
    private TextView time;
    private TextView emptyView;


    public NewOrderVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Badge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        finish = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.finish);
        orderCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.OrderCard);
        cusPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cusPic);
        cusName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cusName);
        CusAdress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CusAdress);
        vendorsNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vendorsNum);
        itemsNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemsNum);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        emptyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);


        orderCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), OrderDetails.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    public void setData(final OrderPresenter data) {

        time.setText(data.getOrderTime());
        cusName.setText(data.getFullName());
        vendorsNum.setText(data.getVendorsCount());
        itemsNum.setText(data.getItemsCount());
        CusAdress.setText(data.getFullAddress());
        Picasso.with(context).load(data.getCustomerPicture()).into(cusPic);

    }

    public void setBadgeColor(int drawable) {
        this.Badge.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
    }

    public void setBadge(String badge) {
        this.Badge.setText(badge);
    }


}


@Override

public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {

    return R.id.swipe;
}

@Override
public void openItem(int position) {

}

@Override
public void closeItem(int position) {

}

@Override
public void closeAllExcept(SwipeLayout layout) {

}

@Override
public void closeAllItems() {

}

@Override
public List<Integer> getOpenItems() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<SwipeLayout> getOpenLayouts() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void removeShownLayouts(SwipeLayout layout) {

}

@Override
public boolean isOpen(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Attributes.Mode getMode() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setMode(Attributes.Mode mode) {

}


  }
```

**My NewOrder Fragment**

> Note: the FinishedOrders tab (fragment) does the same thing as new order but filters the current the Finished status.

```
public class NewOrdersTab extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
OrdersDataAdapter adapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swiperefresh;
private TextView emptyView;
ArrayList<OrderPresenter> modelData;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_orders_tab_frag, container, false);

    modelData = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    swiperefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    swiperefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.color_error, R.color.colorInfo);
    adapter = new OrdersDataAdapter(modelData, getActivity());
    emptyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);

    OrderRepository.fetchOrders("awaiting-shipment", getActivity(), new DataFetch() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ArrayList<OrderPresenter> data) {
            swiperefresh.setRefreshing(true);

            if (data.size() != 0) {
                swiperefresh.setRefreshing(true);

                emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                modelData.clear();
                modelData.addAll(data);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {

                emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                emptyView.setText(getString(R.string.No_New_Orders));
            }
            swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

  }
```

Comment: I would try to change data inside the adapter. It worked for me

Comment: @LongLuong how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I just added these two lines after I make the request..!

```
 orders.remove(position);
 notifyItemRemoved(position);
 //notifyDataSetChanged(position);
```

Comment: @LongLuong yes, with these two lines